# Recording Webcam and Audio with ffmpeg on Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, audio, ffmpeg, recording

I am trying to record video + audio with `ffmpeg` of my defualt webcam.

This works with video:

```
ffmpeg -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0  -ab 64 -ar 22050 -ac 1 output.avi
```

but no sound is recorded. Is it possible to do that with Windows?

I have two web cams and a virtual screen sharing driver commncetd. Is it possible to specufy another input video? I tried changing `-i {1..9}` but this did not help.

Comment: I've been looking for a similar project, but posts on their help forum indicate that Windows can't capture audio. However, many of these posts are old. It might be possible using OSS, but I'm not sure if OSS has been ported to Windows.

Comment: What is OSS, Open Source Software? Could you be more specific with your answer?

Comment: Sorry, OSS in this context is Open Sound System.  It's one of the input devices that ffmpeg supports.

Comment: try it with the "dshow" input option